# Using Mid-Points for Area of Triangle does not support answer.

Tags: geometry, determinant, analytic-geometry, area

I was preparing for my end-sem exams and I ran into this problem that asks me to figure out the area of the triangle given its mid-points. Either I could've computed the vertices of the triangle which is very tedious or use this fact for $\Delta ABC$ with mid-points of sides $AB, BC, CA$ as $D, E, F$ respectively:

> $$\text{ar}(\Delta DEF)=\dfrac{1}{4}\text{ar}(\Delta ABC)$$

I use the latter for $D(-1/5, 5/2), E(7, 3), F(7/2, 7/2)$ and build up the following expression:

$$\text{ar}(\Delta ABC)=4\cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{2}\left|\begin{matrix}7/2 && 7/2 && 1\\ 7 &&3 && 1\\ -1/5 && 5/2 && 1\end{matrix}\right|}_{\text{ar}(\Delta DEF)}=\left|\begin{matrix}7 && 7 && 2\\ 7 &&3 && 1\\ -1/5 && 5/2 && 1\end{matrix}\right|=10.7 \text{ sq. units}$$

This does not agree with the answer in my textbook which says it to be $11$ sq. units. Is there a mistake in my reasoning? Thanks

Comment: Your reasoning is fine, check your arithmetic.

Comment: @Vasya I get $10.7$ for the absolute value of the last determinant.  Is there an earlier mistake that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @saulspatz That was my first thought, I also got $10.7$ after checking. Could be just a rounding issue.

Comment: Or maybe the question has a typo in the coordinates of the mid-points. I'm not sure it's about rounding off because we're supposed to provide answers to at least $2$ decimal places.

Comment: Typo sounds likely.

Comment: I just tried replacing the value $-1/5$ (which just looked bad and the cause of all this issue) with $-1/2$ and I got $11$ sq. units. Thanks guys @saulspatz and $Vasya for helping through.